# Minimal subset of Lie algebra generators required to complete the algebra via the bracket?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let's say I have a subset of the generators for a real, semisimple Lie algebra. To find the full set of generators, I can take the Lie bracket of every element in my subset until it becomes closed. For any Lie algebra, there should be a minimal subset (maybe not unique) with the property that I recover the full Lie algebra by recursively applying the Lie bracket.

1. Does this subset have a name?
2. Is the form or even the cardinality of this subset known for any of the real semisimple Lie algebras?

Comment: A Lie algebra is a vector space, so you need to know a basis $ \{X_k\}$ and all non-zero commutators of basis elements $[X_i\, , \,X_j]$ for $i<j.$ Any other approach depends heavily on the Lie algebra you are talking about.

Comment: @MariusS.L.:  I take the question to be: given a Lie algebra $L$ what is the minimum cardinality of a subset of $L$ when generates $L$ via linear combinations and Lie brackets.  So, for example, for the Lie algebra of the Lie group $SO(3)$, the Lie algebra is $3$-dimensional but any independent subset of $2$ vectors generates the entire Lie algebra via brackets and linear combinations.

Comment: @JasonDeVito But what does "given a Lie algebra" even mean? How do two elements "generate" $SO(3)$? You need a basis, Lie brackets or not.

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes, that's the question I'm trying to get at, thanks for the example.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I guess this answers my question about cardinality. Can anything be said about form, i.e., how can I identify a pair(s) of elements that will generate a given algebra?